# io += port: value += is not a member of Chisel.Bundle

Tags: chisel

I am trying to compile Zhe Mao's xactor package (guarded atomic actions for Chisel), but get the error

```
value += is not a member of Chisel.Bundle
```

on the statement

```
io += port
```

Is there a Chisel version other than latest.release which does support this construct?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to use the Chisel "master" found at (https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel), which points to the latest development head. The README covers using a "self-publish" model where you include a local SNAPSHOT release you compiled yourself instead of the `latest.release`.

Here is a copy of the instructions in case something happens to the github Chisel README page:

> ```
> $ git clone https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel.git
> $ cd chisel
> ```
>
> Compile and install your local copy of Chisel:
>
> ```
> $ make clean test publish-local
> ```
>
> In order to use your local copy of Chisel in your own projects, you
>   will need to update your build.sbt files so the Chisel library
>   dependency is satisfied by your local copy. Replace
>
> ```
> libraryDependencies += "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel" % "latest.release"
> ```
>
> with:
>
> ```
> libraryDependencies += "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel" % "2.3-SNAPSHOT"
> ```